# Amazon Putty connect

Tags: amazon-ec2, putty

I am trying to connect to Amazon EC2 with putty but the key provided by amazon is being  rejected. I destroyed all instances and all key pairs. Then I created new ones and still the same problem.

Anybody?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Did you read the [Amazon docs appendix on PuTTY](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonEC2/gsg/2007-01-19/putty.html)? It goes into what you have to do to connect with PuTTY, because:

> PuTTY does not natively support the
>   private key format generated by Amazon
>   EC2. Fortunately PuTTY has a tool
>   called PuTTYgen which can convert keys
>   to its internal format.

(This was the first hit on a search for "putty ec2" btw.)

Comment: PuTTYgen - yes I have used this.
Amazon is asking me for username / password !!!???????

Comment: Did you follow every step of those instructions carefully?

Answer (score 0):

See this [link](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/GettingStartedGuide/index.html?putty.html) for instructions on how to create a key that it will work with Putty.